# Problem from Ravi Vakil's AG notes

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Exercise 1.3.O is the following: If $X$ is a topological space, show that fibered products always exist in the category of open sets of $X$, by describing what a fibered product is. (Hint: it has a one-word description).

I've been staring at the following example that I've tried to base my solution on:

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and try to compute $A\times_C B$, where $A=(1,2)$, $B=(2,3)$, $C=(0,1)$ and we have obvious maps $A\to C$ by $x\mapsto x-1$ and $B\to C$ by $x\mapsto x-2$.

Since the fibered product would have to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ I'm sort of clueless about how to proceed. It can't be the intersection, since in this case it's empty and that trivially won't work. It can't be the union, since then the induced map is not unique.

It seems like this should be completely trivial based on the hint?

Comment: It _is_ the intersection. The morphisms in the category of open sets are the inclusions.

Answer (score 2):

Fibered products in that category are intersections. Your problems arise from wrong assumptions: indeed there's no arrow from $A$ to $C$ (here arrows are inclusions in the strict sense, so you should have $A \subset C$).

Comment: Ah, that explains it. The problem was a bit vague and I assumed the arrows were continuous maps...

Comment: The category of open sets has that strict definition in order to consider presheaves on a topological space (in the naive sense) as functors from suitable categories.